# Having trouble displaying related fields in Django 2.0 template

Tags: python, django

I am a newbie to Django and cannot figure this out from any of my searches.

I am having trouble displaying related fields in my Django 2.0 template.  There are 2 fields in my model referring to the same foreign model. What is the best way to handle this?

I greatly appreciate any assistance with this.

**Model**

```
class Clients(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    type = models.ForeignKey(Types, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    division = models.ForeignKey(Divisions, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    address1 = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    address2 = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=75, null=True, blank=True)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=75, null=True, blank=True)
    fax = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)
    website = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    pb_support_rate = models.ForeignKey(SupportRates, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='pb_rate', blank=True)
    px_support_rate = models.ForeignKey(SupportRates, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='px_rate', blank=True)
```

**View**

```
class ClientsDetailView(DetailView):
    model = models.Clients
    context_object_name = 'client_details'
    template_name = 'client_details.html'
```

**Template**

```
<tr>
    <th style=" border: 1px solid black;padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;white-space: nowrap;">PB Support Rate</th>
    <td style=" border: 1px solid black;padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;white-space: nowrap;" >{{ object.pb_support_rate|default_if_none:'' }}</td>
    <td style=" border: 1px solid black;padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;white-space: nowrap;text-align:right;" >{{ object.pb_rate__rate_amount }}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Perhaps something like: `{{ object.SupportRates.rate|default_if_none:'' }}`

Comment: What does the SupportRates model look like? And why do you have two FKs to the same model?

Comment: Here is the model for Rates
`class SupportRates(models.Model):
        rate_description = models.CharField(max_length=150)
        rate_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
        rate_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)`

Comment: {{ object.pb_support_rate }} pulls in the rate description instead of the amount.  I need the rate description and the rate amount separately from the table.

Comment: `{{ object.pb_support_rate }}` is the related object. If you want an attribute of that then do another dot lookup: `{{ object.pb_support_rate.rate_amount }}`.  You can do as many `dot` lookups as you like, e.g. `{{ a.b.c.d }}`.

Comment: Thanks so much!  That worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the field name in the template. It doesn't matter whether there are 1, 2 or 10 foreign keys to the same model.

The field name is `pb_support_rate` so `{{ object.pb_support_rate }}` should work fine.

The model doesn't have a field name `pb_rate__rate_amount` so I don't know what you expect `object.pb_rate__rate_amount` to do - perhaps you mean

```
{{ object.pb_support_rate.rate_amount }}
```